# Can I use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) with Google Compute Engine and without using Firebase?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, google-compute-engine, phonegap

I am quite new for mobile application development and currently analyzing the solution architecture for my web and mobile application. I am using `Google Compute Engine` as a back-end component where my web application will be deployed.

For generating mobile application I am planning to use `Phonegap` and exploring how can I send the push notification with the help of `FCM` and `GCE`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I may ask .. why not use FireBase as a component in the solution in addition to other components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely call the FCM API to send messages from a GCE instance. In fact, since it's a straightforward HTTP API, you can call it from almost any environment.

Of course you will be using Firebase in that case, as in: you'll need to create a project in the Firebase console (or attach Firebase to your existing Google Cloud project), to get the necessary keys to send a message.

And your clients will need to use the Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK to receive those messages.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just want to know, is there a separate billing required if I attach Firebase in my existing Google Cloud project or I use a separate Firebase console?

Comment: All Firebase related billing goes through your existing Google Cloud billing account. But FCM is completely free, so won't generate a charge to that account anyway. For full details on Firebase's pricing, see https://firebase.google.com/pricing